# What are the most recent devopments with applying fractals to economics?

Tags: economics, fractals

I was researching fractals for my senior mathematics presentation and discovered that one of the most recent pioneers in that section of the field was able to apply fractal mathematics to the field of economics.  One of his first discoveries was finding a fractal pattern to fluctuations in cotton prices. 
What further advancements have been made in the applications of fractals to economics?

Answer (score 0):

Fractal and chaos theory both were very popular in Economics in the early 90's but to the best of my knowledge it was more of an academic fad: no lasting advances were made.

Comment: Fractals and ergodic theory are very active areas of research. I don't know if there are any applications to economy though.

Comment: @TomasPersson: There are some but they are quite marginal in Economics.